# Turning a recursive function with for loop, to pure recursive

Tags: c, recursion, powerset

I have made this function to print  powerset within a given array,
I Inherently built the function with for loop as a base, and then convert it to pure recursive, but i seem to hit a roadbloack.

here's the function:

```
void powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index)
{
    if (index == n)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; i<n; i++)
    {
        p[pos] = arr[i];

        for (int j = 0; j <= pos; j++)
            printf("%d ", p[j]);
        printf("\n");

        powerSet(arr, p, n, pos + 1, i + 1);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

here is my code so far, for some reason, it only prints out

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

snippet:

```
void powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index)
{
    if (index == n)
    {
        return;
    }
    p[pos] = arr[index];
    PrintRec(0, pos, p);
    powerSet(arr, p, n, pos + 1, index + 1);
}
void getSubSet(int*arr, int*p, int n, int i, int end)
{
    if (i > end)
        return;
    powerSet(arr, p, n, i, end);
    getSubSet(arr, p, n, i + 1, end);
}
void PrintRec(int j, int end, int* p)
{
    if (j > end)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d ", p[j]);
    PrintRec(j + 1, end, p);
}
```

main:

```
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int temp[5];
getSubSet(arr, temp, n, 0, 0);
```

EDIT: Posted the solution!

Comment: What is the problem? "Roadblock" is not a technical term.

Comment: Where is the version of your code that is a "pure recursive"? The code you've included has the for loop still

Comment: @Jabberwocky i simply dont know how to go from here.
chris, i am aware, i simply can't understand how to go from here to pure recursive.

Comment: What happens when you run the program? Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: Hint: changing just the `for (int j = 0; j <= pos; j++) printf("%d ", p[j]);` part into a pure recursive function would be something like `PrintRec(0, pos, p); void PrintRec(int j, int end, int* p) { if (j > end) return; printf("%d ", p[j]); PrintRec(j + 1, end, p); }`

Comment: Jabber, the program is working and is displaying the result as intended.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks! this example helped a lot!

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figured it out, here is the answer for anybody who cares:

```
void main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int temp[4];
    powerSet(arr, temp, n, 0, 0);
}

void powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index)
{
    if (index >= n)
    {
        return;
    }
    p[pos] = arr[index];
    PrintRec(0, pos, p);
    powerSet(arr, p, n, pos + 1, index + 1);
    powerSet(arr, p, n, pos, index+1);

}
void PrintRec(int j, int end, int* p)
{
    if (j > end)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d ", p[j]);
    PrintRec(j + 1, end, p);
}
```

output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 3
2
2 3
3
```

Comment: the function that generates the powerset should not be coupled with the function that prints the result - this is known as a side effect and you should learn to nip these in the bud sooner than later.